# Java: Basic agenda program where one can manipulate their events and get notified of current week or day events if wishes to

Tags: java, eclipse

I thought I could make this simple program without asking for human help and wasting their time, but my "ideas" have stumbled here. Google helped me till now but this as far I could get, unfortunately. So any help is extremely appreciated and before I begin please note that I am at the very beginning with Java.

So as the title says this is a mini-agenda program like `Google Keep` let's just say, where a user is greeted with a console-based menu that looks like this:

1. Register personal events
2. Current day or week events
3. Delete events
4. Edit events
5. Close Agenda

When he/she goes to option 2 the program should list the events properly. For now, it just shows all of them. Actually, this is the code from main:

```
public class Agenda
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        Event event = new Event();
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        //System.out.println(date.toString());
        //System.out.println(hourMinutesSeconds.toString());



        boolean agenda = true;
        while (agenda)
        {
            System.out.println("Menu");
            System.out.println("====");
            System.out.println("1. Register personal events");
            System.out.println("2. Current week/day events");
            System.out.println("3. Delete events");
            System.out.println("4. Edit events");
            System.out.println("5. Close agenda");
            int choice = sc1.nextInt();
            switch (choice)
            {
                 case 1:
                 {   
                      int exit = 1;
                      String save = "";
                      while (exit == 1)
                      {    
                           System.out.println("Register personal events");
                           System.out.println("=========================");

                           System.out.println("Your name:");
                           person.setName(sc2.nextLine());

                           System.out.println("Person phone number:");
                           person.setPhoneNumber(sc2.nextLine());

                           System.out.println("Add details about someone's anniversary(optional: schedule a date in the format as follows (hour/minutes/seconds day/month/year))");
                           event.setBirthDay(sc2.nextLine());


                           System.out.println("Add details about the conference(optional: schedule a date in the format as follows (hour/minutes/seconds day/month/year))");
                           event.setMeeting(sc2.nextLine());

                           System.out.println("Add details about the debate(optional: schedule a date in the format as follows (hour/minutes/seconds day/month/year))");
                           event.setDebate(sc2.nextLine());


                           System.out.println("Save the event?yes\\no");
                           save = sc2.nextLine();
                           if (save.equals("yes"))
                           {
                               String fileName = person.toString().substring(6, person.toString().indexOf("\n")) + ".txt";
                               EventSaver.saveToFile(person.toString() + event.toString(), fileName);
                           }


                           System.out.println("Do you wish to add more events? 1-Yes, 0-No");
                           exit = sc1.nextInt();

                      }
                      break;
                 }

                 case 2:
                 {

                      String[] events = EventSaver.readEvents();
                      for (int i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
                      {

                          System.out.println(events[i]);

                      }
                      break;
                 }

                 case 3:
                 {
                      break;

                 }

                 case 4:
                 {
                      break;

                 }

                 case 5:
                 {
                     agenda = false;
                     sc1.close();
                     sc2.close();
                     System.out.println("Agenda closed");
                     break;
                 }
                 default:
                 {
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid option...\ngoing back to main menu");
                 }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The EventSaver Class:

```
public class EventSaver 
{
    private static String FILENAME = "D:\\my_stuff\\some_dir\\some_dir\\Workspace\\EventAgenda\\src\\";

    public static void saveToFile(String content, String fileName)
    {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try 
        {
             fw = new FileWriter(FILENAME + fileName);
             bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
             bw.write(content);

             System.out.println("Event saved");

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
             e.printStackTrace();

        } 
        finally 
        {
             try 
             {
                  if (bw != null)
                  {
                       bw.close();
                  }
                  if (fw != null)
                  {
                       fw.close();
                  }
             } 
             catch (IOException ex) 
             {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
    }


    public static String[] readEvents() throws IOException
    {
        File folder = new File("D:\\my_stuff\\some_dir\\some_dir\\Workspace\\EventAgenda\\src\\");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        String fileContents = "";
        String[] content;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
        {
            File file = listOfFiles[i];
            if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt"))
            {

                fileContents += FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8") + "\n";

            }
        }
        content = fileContents.split("\n");
        return content;
```

After the event is saved the `.txt` file belonging to the specific user looks like this:

```
Name: Bob
Phone Number: 0741123458
Birthday: Elena, at LongDrinks(19:00:00 19/06/2017)
Conference: Current stage of the project SMFA(20:00:00 24/06/2017)
Debate: The meaning of this world(21:30:00 19/06/2017)
```

I tried getting those dates and compare them somehow but in vain with this code:

```
public class SetEvents {

    if (event.toString().indexOf("(") != -1)
    {
          String[] eventTimeAndDate = (event.toString().substring(event.toString().indexOf("(") + 1, event.toString().indexOf(")"))).split(" ");
          String[] eventTime = eventTimeAndDate[0].split(":");
          String[] eventDate = eventTimeAndDate[1].split("/");

          Time hourMinutesSeconds = new Time();
          hourMinutesSeconds.setHour(Integer.parseInt(eventTime[0]));
          hourMinutesSeconds.setMinute(Integer.parseInt(eventTime[1]));
          hourMinutesSeconds.setSecond(Integer.parseInt(eventTime[2]));

          MyDate date = new MyDate(Integer.parseInt(eventDate[2]), Integer.parseInt(eventDate[1]), Integer.parseInt(eventDate[0]));              
    }
```

But with this I can extract only the first date occurrence from the file and I need to get all occurrences, compare them somehow using the other classes to find the current week and day events and display them properly when choosing option 2. How could i do it?
Thanks

Comment: You got slightly trapped by making your file human-readable. I think it would be easier for you if you save your events in slightly different format: `(<Date>) <EventDescription>`. That will allow you to simplify searching for dates, because each line would contain date at the very start, and everything else will be event description until end of line in file.

Answer (score 1):

in Java there is a second `indexOf`  method

```
indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)
```

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified substring, starting at the specified index.

(see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

So you could go like this:

```
int startAt = 0;
String evt = event.toString();
while (evt.indexOf("(", startAt) != -1){

      startAt = indexOf("(", startAt)+2;

      String[] eventTimeAndDate = (event.toString().substring(event.toString().indexOf("(") + 1, event.toString().indexOf(")"))).split(" ");
      String[] eventTime = eventTimeAndDate[0].split(":");
      String[] eventDate = eventTimeAndDate[1].split("/");

      Time hourMinutesSeconds = new Time();
      hourMinutesSeconds.setHour(Integer.parseInt(eventTime[0]));
      hourMinutesSeconds.setMinute(Integer.parseInt(eventTime[1]));
      hourMinutesSeconds.setSecond(Integer.parseInt(eventTime[2]));

      MyDate date = new MyDate(Integer.parseInt(eventDate[2]), Integer.parseInt(eventDate[1]), Integer.parseInt(eventDate[0]));              
    }
```

EDIT: Didn't test it, but within this while loop you should be able to extract all Dates you got

Answer (score 0):

I thought to share the solved problem of this question, at least to some extent. Just a way that works ok:

```
public static void currentWeekOrDayEvents(String[] evt)
 {
     DateFormat originalDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy");
     String eventsDate = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < evt.length; i++)
     {

         if (evt[i].indexOf("(") != -1)
         { 
              eventsDate = evt[i].substring(evt[i].indexOf("(") + 1, evt[i].indexOf(")"));
              try
              {
                   if (isDateInCurrentWeek(originalDateFormat.parse(eventsDate)))
                   {
                       System.out.println(evt[i]);
                   }
              }
              catch (ParseException e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }


         }
     }
 }

public static boolean isDateInCurrentWeek(Date date) 
 {
      Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      int week = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
      int year = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      Calendar targetCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      targetCalendar.setTime(date);
      int targetWeek = targetCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
      int targetYear = targetCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      return week == targetWeek && year == targetYear;

 }
```